# HttpTransportSE .call() method has no action

Tags: java, android, http, ksoap2

I'm trying to make an Android App that gets the weather based off a zipcode you enter, and that also displays the time in EST and GMT format. I am using webservices (WSDLs) and have the code written to access it, the code is below:

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP";
    NAMESPACE = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/";
    METHOD_NAME = "GetCityWeatherByZIP";
    URL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl";

    txtZIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
    temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTemp);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
    {
        property.name = "zipcode";
        property.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
        property.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        property.setValue(txtZIP.getText().toString());
    }

    request.addProperty(property);

    //request.addProperty("zipcode", txtZIP.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "btnZIP pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE androidHTTP = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 600);

    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In try statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        androidHTTP.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // SoapPrimitive resp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        if(result != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In IF statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //temp.append("in IF statement, result not null");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In ELSE statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //temp.append("in IF statement, result IS null");
        }

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "XML Pull exe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that with the `androidHTTP.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` method, nothing is happening. I have Toast methods to show what is being executed, and the furthest I get is into the try block, but never into the if statement.

I have tried looking around seeing what might be the cause and a solution, but I can't seem to find anything for this specific problem. I've extended the time-out for the server to 600 and even made the implicitType to true, but nothing is working. I know I am using SoapEnvelope.VER10 for this method, but I have two other methods where I used VER11 and VER12 and there's no change. If anyone might have an idea as to what might be going on, I'd really appreciate the help. Also, the AndroidManifest.xml has the necessary uses-permission line to access the internet.

Comment: try changing androidHTTP.call to androidHttpTransport.call

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: do you receive an error or just simply nothing happens?  Maybe some info in the log?

Comment: are you trying to run this straight from the activity class? I don't think android allows that you have to start a new thread and run soap requests from their.

Comment: Hey I know it might not be any use now but there's something called Async  task which you might want to look up that would remove the need of the extra classes to handle the SOAP request and put the code in the main class but still start a new thread. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!!!! WORKING CONFIRMED !!!

main

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

public static String rslt,thread;
SoapMiddleMan c;

EditText txtZIP;
TextView weather;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    txtZIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipCode);
    weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);

  }

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    try{
            // condition for keeping the main thread asleep
            thread = "START";

            // create a new webservice caller thread
            c = new SoapMiddleMan();

            // join the new thread, start it and then select what webservice you want to access
            c.join();c.setZip(txtZIP.getText().toString()); c.start();

            // keep this thread asleep while the service thread is running
            while(thread=="START")
            {   
                try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        rslt="Failed2";
                    }
            }
        }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    weather.setText(rslt);
}
}
```

middleman

```
public class SoapMiddleMan extends Thread {

private String zip;
private SoapSenderClass cs;

public void run(){

    try{
         cs=new SoapSenderClass();
         String resp=cs.getWeather(zip);
         MainActivity.rslt=resp; //public string in calling activity
         System.out.println("reached 2 \n");
        }catch(Exception ex)

        {
            MainActivity.rslt=ex.toString();
        }


        MainActivity.thread = "done";
    }

public void setZip(String searchZip)
{
    zip = searchZip;
}

}
```

Caller

```
public class SoapSenderClass{

String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP";
String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/";
String METHOD_NAME = "GetCityWeatherByZIP";
String URL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl";


public String getWeather(String zipcode)
{
    try{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();

    property.setName("ZIP");
    property.setType(String.class);
    property.setValue(zipcode);
    request.addProperty(property);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

    String resultValue = response.toString();

    return resultValue;

} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "Failed to get ID";
}

}
}
```

I have simplified your caller code and I changed the name of the addproperty to ZIP which is what it looks like the input is called in the WSDL.  Removed the brackets for the property calls removed Namespace which isnt needed as far as I can tell.

Comment: Wow thank you for all that! I am going to try that either later tonight or tomorrow morning. One thing that I am thinking of though is that tutorials that I have seen from other people and what someone else in the same class did, they did them all from the same Java class. I will give this a try anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it depends on the version you're using because I went through exactly the same steps I had it in the activity class and then split it into a thread.

Comment: I see, one question I have though is about the Activity.rslt = resp; line in the SoapMiddleMan class. As I'm trying it now, there is no rslt from the Acticity class, so what exactly is it?

Comment: Should have put a comment for that line

Comment: Replace Activity with your main activitys name. The public static rslt in your main activity will hold the result of the soap request you then use rslt in your main activity as you need to.

Comment: I see, and I'm also assuming that in the main activity I should call the run() method you made in the MiddleMan class, right?

Comment: It automatically calls the run method.

Comment: You might wanna switch round the c.start and c.setZipCode

Comment: Sorry, but even after making a new project with what you recommended, I'm still having problems with the call() method.

Comment: I'll create a project with your coding and see if I can figure it out that way. Everything looks as it should. What does the Web service return? Is it a String?

Comment: Yes it takes a String as a parameter and returns Strings. If you can, start a chat with me because I can't start one. This project is due at 5PM EDT.

Comment: couldnt start a chat but edited answer it definitely works.  Though the result is unedited