# Exception when calling a Web Service

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am trying to call a Web Service sending a SOAP envelope, but i am getting this error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=answerIden"

What may be the problem? is it related to a way I am using to call it?

This is how I call it:

```
public static Boolean sendAnswers(String ticket, TdcSystem system) {
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(TdcService.NAMESPACE, TdcService.METHOD_NAME[TdcService.TipoMetodo.ANSWER_IDEN.getValue()]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        sobre.dotNet = false;
        sobre.implicitTypes = true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(TdcService.URL);

        String xml = buildXmlRequest(ticket, system);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)sobre.getResponse();

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TdcService.METHOD_NAME[TdcService.TipoMetodo.ANSWER_IDEN.getValue()]);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml, HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpPost.addHeader("", TdcService.METHOD_NAME[TdcService.TipoMetodo.ANSWER_IDEN.getValue()]);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Auditing.LogError(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can you point me to the right direction, please?

For you to know, I have to call answerIden method of http://190.12.95.42/tdc/ServiceTDC/TDC.php service, and TdcService definition is as follows:

```
package cl.virtualice.tdc.helpers;

/**
 * Created by Jaime on 24-10-2015.
 */
public class TdcService {
    public enum TipoMetodo {
        ANSWER_IDEN(0), CHECK_IDEN(1), CHECK_3G(2), RAN(3);

        private int _value;

        TipoMetodo(int Value) {
            this._value = Value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return _value;
        }

        public static TipoMetodo fromInt(int i) {
            for (TipoMetodo b : TipoMetodo .values()) {
                if (b.getValue() == i) { return b; }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Configurationwsdl";
    public static final String URL="http://190.12.95.42/tdc/ServiceTDC/TDC.php";
    public static final String[] METHOD_NAME = {"answerIden", "checkiDen", "check3G", "RAN"};
    public static final String[] SOAP_ACTION = {"urn:Configurationwsdl#answerIden", "urn:Configurationwsdl#checkiDen", "urn:Configurationwsdl#check3G", "urn:Configurationwsdl#RAN"};
}
```

Comment: On which line does it throw the exception? can you also show the logcat?

Comment: In HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);.... logcat appears empty

Comment: well one thing you are missing is `transporte.call()`

Comment: transporte is an unused variable, and in fact, I have deleted that line. The problem is that Uri.host is null... so, how can I set uri.host to the URL of the server? I cannot do it in httpPost constructor.

Comment: Well, you are passing URL only to constructor of HttpTransportSE. So in order to have a target URL defined, you need to use your `transporte`. Check here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824743/2160877

Comment: That post does not work for me, because I don't have a SoapObject... I have an XML envelope as a string. How can I assign it?